# Help with grid lines in a pgfplot (Version 3)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The following display is that of a line and of a parabola on the Cartesian plane with grid lines.  The grid lines are drawn nicely ... but to draw the grid lines I have included the `axis` options `xtick={-7,-6,...,7},` and `ytick={-5,-4,...,6},`, and these options print all the numbers along the axes which makes a mess.  Except for `-3` and `3` along the x-axis and `4` along the y-axis, I would like all the labels for the tick marks removed.  (Since I have a grid, I guess the tick marks themselves are redundant.)

I suppose that I don't need the tick marks or the labels `-3`, `3`, and `4` for the tick marks printed.  I could put the coordinates `(-3,0)`, `(3,0)` and `(0,4)` in nodes and use the option `fill=white`.  Any aesthetic suggestions would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},major grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!10}, clip=false,
    xmin=-7,xmax=7,
    ymin=-5,ymax=6,
    axis lines=middle,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
    xtick={-7,-6,...,7},ytick={-5,-4,...,6},
    xticklabel style={fill=none},
    yticklabel style={fill=none},
    extra x ticks={-3,3},
    extra x tick labels={\,$-3$, $3$},
    extra x tick style={x tick label style={font=\tiny,fill=white}},
    extra y ticks={4},
    extra y tick labels={$4$},
    extra y tick style={y tick label style={above left, font=\tiny,fill=white}},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-6.75:1.5] {(4/3) * x + 4} node[anchor=south east,pos=0.1,fill=white,font=\footnotesize]{$y = f(x)$};
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-4.5:4.5] {-(4/9) * x^2 + 4} node[anchor=south west,pos=0.6,fill=white,font=\footnotesize]{$y = g(x)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do it is to write:

```
xticklabels={,,,,-3,,}
```

and so on. Of course this is tedious and long to do. The method you were using was mostly correct: using only the extra tick labels to draw the ones you need, although you don't need `\,` in them.

If you want to make the regular labels empty, you have two ways of doing it, both valid (I used them both in my code):

```
xticklabels={\empty},
yticklabels={,,},
```

Also, you can apply the style to the tick labels. You can either set a style to the regular and extra tick labels independently, or you can use the regular `yticklabel style={},` and it will apply to both.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},major grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!10}, clip=false,
    xmin=-7,xmax=7,
    ymin=-5,ymax=6,
    axis lines=middle,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
    xtick={-7,-6,...,7},
    ytick={-5,-4,...,6},
    xticklabels={\empty},
    yticklabels={,,},
    extra x ticks={-3,3},
    extra x tick labels={$-3$, $3$},
    extra y ticks={4},
    extra y tick labels={$4$},
    yticklabel style={anchor=south east},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-6.75:1.5] {(4/3) * x + 4} node[anchor=south east,pos=0.1,fill=white,font=\footnotesize]{$y = f(x)$};
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-4.5:4.5] {-(4/9) * x^2 + 4} node[anchor=south west,pos=0.6,fill=white,font=\footnotesize]{$y = g(x)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can do tedious.  Since there are four commas before `-3` and "nothing" typeset before them in `xticklabels={,,,,-3,,,,,3,,,,,}`, the four tick marks `-7`,  `-6`, `-5`, and `-4` are not typeset.  How many commas would be needed between -3 and 3.  If `0` is not considered a tick mark, five commas would be needed, and if `0` is considered a tick mark, four commas would be needed.

Comment: @user74973 Whether you explicitly say `0` in that list or not, it'd be the same. I think it's irrelevant for the 0 tick mark.

Comment: Are you saying that the `0` tick mark is not printed?  If that is the case, I could have `xticklabels={,,,,-3,,,0,,,3,,,,,},`.

Comment: I would like to move the tick marks down a bit - maybe 2.5pt - so that they don't interfere with the parabola. I forgot the syntax to do this in an axis environment.

Comment: @user74973 Indeed, it's not printed. Write `xticklabel style={yshift=-2.5pt},` to shift them.

Comment: Do you have a guess for the reason that the person writing the code for the `axis` environment to decide that `yticklabels={,,},` is going to give the same display as `yticklabels={\empty}`?

Comment: @user74973 No, maybe it's specified in the manual though.

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{algebraic}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(-6,-3.5)(4.9,6.9) % boundry found manually
    % axes
    \psaxes[labels = none]{->}(0,0)(-5.5,-3.5)(4.5,6.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \uput[300](-3,0){$-3$}
    \uput[230](3,0){$3$}
    \uput[135](0,4){$4$}
    % labels
    \uput[150](-4.5,-2){$y = f(x)$}
    \uput[30](!2 20 9 div){$y = g(x)$}
    % graphs
    \psplot[linecolor = blue]{-5}{1.5}{4/3*x+4}
    \psplot[linecolor = red]{-4}{4}{-4/9*x^2+4}
  \end{pspicture}
 \caption{Add caption here.}
 \label{figure:something}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

This is not an elegant solution, but it may help you:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[grid=major,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},major grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!10}, clip=false,
xmin=-7,xmax=5,
ymin=-5,ymax=6,
axis lines=middle,
enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
extra x ticks={-7,-6,...,5},extra y ticks={-5,-4,...,6},
xticklabel style={fill=none},
yticklabel style={fill=none},
extra x tick labels={$\,$,$\,$,$\,$,$\,$,$\quad-3$,$\,$,$\,$,$\,$,$\,$,$\,$,$3\;$},
extra x tick style={x tick label style={font=\tiny}},
extra y tick labels={$\,$,$\,$,$\,$,$\,$,$\,$,$0$,$\,$,$\,$,$\,$,$4$},
extra y tick style={y tick label style={above left, font=\tiny}},
axis line style={latex-latex},
axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west},axis equal
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-6.75:1.5] {(4/3) * x + 4} node[anchor=south east,pos=0.1,fill=white,font=\footnotesize]{$y = f(x)$};
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-4.5:4.5] {-(4/9) * x^2 + 4} node[anchor=south west,pos=0.6,fill=white,font=\footnotesize]{$y = g(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the labels, why do you have `$\,$`?  Why not `$$` or `{}`?  (I see that you had `$\quad-3$,` to move `-3` further from one of the intersections of the graphs of $f$ and $g$.  I think the minus sign does touch the line using just `\,`.  Maybe using `\,\,` or `\ ` would be fine.)

Comment: Because that I wrote trick and no "solution", with `$$` appears math mode, I didn't compiled that way. I prove with `\,` and `\;` but this is not sufficient translation for minus sign, you can try.

Comment: I lowered the tick labels by `2pt`.

Comment: Is another way ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option for code that Alenanno suggested.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},major grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!10}, clip=false,
    xmin=-7,xmax=7,
    ymin=-5,ymax=6,
    axis lines=middle,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
    xtick={-7,-6,...,7},ytick={-5,-4,...,6},
    xticklabels={,,,,$-3$,,,,,3,,,,,},yticklabels={,,,,,,,,,4,,},
    xticklabel style={yshift=-2pt, font=\tiny,fill=white},
    yticklabel style={above left, font=\tiny,fill=white},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-6.75:1.5] {(4/3) * x + 4} node[anchor=south east,pos=0.1,fill=white,font=\footnotesize]{$y = f(x)$};
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-4.5:4.5] {-(4/9) * x^2 + 4} node[anchor=south west,pos=0.6,fill=white,font=\footnotesize]{$y = g(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```